# y axis limit - appears to alter the data that is analysed

Tags: axis, boxplot, yaxis

I have a bunch of data where the hours taken to process an item ranges from 3-3000 hours. most of the data is <1000 hours

I am creating a boxplot of that data.  I have an large number of outliers within the data that I don't need to display, but I do need to analyse.

I have tried to use both 'scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1000))' and 'ylim(0,1000)' that appears to change the data that is used to create the boxplot, I altered the limits to '20' to test this theory and I get a complete plot, which can only be because the method i'm using to limit the axis also limits the range of data analysed.

I'd like to limit the y axis but not limit the range of data that is used in the analysis, what function do I use to accomplish that?

many thanks

Comment: coord_cartesian is what I was after

Answer (score 0):

it appears that it's 'coord_cartesian(ylim = c(nnn,nnn))+' that I needed to use.